# Replacing nested for loops in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I wrote this code but the problem is I have a restriction in my assignment that I can't use nested for loops in my code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void Exchange(int* a, int* b) {
    int var;
    var = *a;           //For swapping or exchanging values. O_o
    *a = *b;
    *b = var;
}
void Algorithm(int array[], int nerd) {
    int i, j, k;                                //This is the actual algorithm which is required. ;)
    for (i = 0; i < nerd;) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < nerd; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[j - 1])
                Exchange(&array[j], &array[j - 1]);
        }
        nerd--;
        for (k = nerd - 1; k > i; k--) {
            if (array[k] < array[k - 1])
                Exchange(&array[k], &array[k - 1]);
           
        }
        i++;

    }
   
    
}
int main() {
    int n, i;
    cout << "\nEnter the count of numbers for the algorithm: ";
    cin >> n;
    int arr[10];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    Algorithm(arr, n);
    cout << "\nFinal Data you entered (after the algorithm performed)";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << " -> " << arr[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its basically a sorting algorithm. You need a sorting algorithm with time complexity O(N) or less than O(N*N). Try quicksort, radix sort or count sort for this.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Yes it is a sorting algorithm but I need a replacement for the nested for loops. I mean I have to implement the exact same algorithm but without nested loops.

Comment: FYI, you can use `std::swap` or exchanging of swapping values.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My bad, I always do that but didn't here.

Comment: So you want to sort the array? Then use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: It seems to be a stupid assignment to me. Is there any reason why nested loops should be replaced? In theory, you can, for example, replace any loop with recursion. But I don't see any reason why someone should do this.

Comment: How about replacing `for (i = 0; i < nerd;)` with `i = 0; while (i < nerd)`?

Comment: You can do a basic bubble sort with only one loop.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I wish I could do that but I am restricted.

Comment: @MikeCAT Did that.

Comment: @HumayunSaeed How was the result?

Comment: @MikeCAT full of errors you can say, and once it worked it didn't sort anything.

Comment: Make the inner loops separate functions and call them from the outer `for` loop.

Comment: @HumayunSaeed Hmmm, it looks working for me. [replace to `while`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eLWbgkvIYHAbIcpD) / [use `std::sort`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3rv8aedMlCeITiwj)

Comment: @Blastfurnace Can you do it for me? I am really really tired rn and have to submit pretty soon.

Comment: @MikeCAT can you share the working code?

Comment: @HumayunSaeed Already done.

Comment: @MikeCAT Alright got it! Thanks mate!

Comment: Not sure if this is counts as "no nested loops", but you could move the loops to seperate functions...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Anyway, the issue has been resolved. Thanks to @MikeCAT

Comment: The professor is not so stupid after all.. we learnt a lesson from this task. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ Maybe he isn't? but it is for sure we learnt something new. At least I did.

Comment: @DanielLangr Loops come with overhead. In a performance-critical application, that adds up quickly. Also, for instruction purposes, it's good to understand how these things work.

Comment: @3Dave So how would you propose to eliminate this overhead while not replacing it with another ones? Suggestions such as moving the inner loop into a separate function does not do it and even can add more overhead. The accepted answer is, IMO, even worse, since it is full of costly integer modulo operations.

Comment: @DanielLangr Both modulus versions in my answer now each have modulus-free alternatives. :-) I don't think using one loop will be faster than using two loops though. On the contrary, I think it may trick the optimizer to not do as good as it could have.

Comment: @DanielLangr The purpose of the exercise is to understand what loop constructs are doing. Very few engineers actually write assembly these days, but we still teach it because having an understanding of what the compiler is doing. A loop is just a `jmp` (or `jnz`, etc) with a counter. This whole question could be replaced by a variant of FizzBuzz.

Comment: @DanielLangr One interview question I ask is "Implement this function that does <blah> with recursion." Followed immediately by, "Now remove the recursion." The right answer after the first part is, "Define recursion." Anything that can be done with a recursive call can be done with a `std::stack` and eliminates the function call overhead (and lets you tweak the stack frame), which can add up very quickly. In an application where sub-millisecond timing is crucial, these things matter.

Comment: @3Dave Function call overhead with recursion is very low. I don't think you can generally say that using `std::stack` instead will be faster. Using `std::stack` has overhead as well. Could you show us any benchmark that proves that the "classic" recursion is slower? At best using some real recursive problem such as quicksort.

Comment: @DanielLangr Use of `stack` is just one way to do it; a fixed-sized array would work just as well (and that's one way we simulate recursion in shaders). Yes, call overhead is very low, but it's non-zero. Admittedly this is the sort of edge optimization that doesn't apply in most circumstances, but it's valid nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One loop using modulus on the one loop counter:

```
#include <utility> // std::swap

void Algorithm(int array[], int nerd) {
    int max = nerd * (nerd - 1);

    for(int i = 1; i < max; ++i) {
        // If at start of the removed inner loop, skip i % nerd == 0
        if(i % nerd == 0) ++i;

        if (array[i % nerd] < array[(i-1) % nerd])
            std::swap(array[i % nerd], array[(i - 1) % nerd]);

    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sTaYsb4e4)

---

Without modulus, decreasing `nerd` and restarting with `i = 1` each time `i == nerd`:

```
void Algorithm(int array[], int nerd) {
    for(int i = 1; nerd > 1; ++i) {
        if(i == nerd) { // start of the removed inner loop
            --nerd; // the highest number will already be in place
            i = 1;
        }

        if (array[i] < array[i - 1])
            std::swap(array[i], array[i - 1]);        
    }
    std::cout << "ted " << nerd << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cfG3acWf3)

---

An alternative to quit looping early if no swaps were made last round:

```
void Algorithm(int array[], int nerd) {
    if(nerd < 2) return;
    bool done = true;
    for(int i = 1;; ++i) {
        if(i % nerd == 0) {
            if(done) break;
            ++i;
            done = true;
        }

        if (array[i % nerd] < array[(i-1) % nerd]) {
            std::swap(array[i % nerd], array[(i-1) % nerd]);
            done = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4GPx7sxGo)

---

The alternative without modulus and with the decreasing `nerd` optimization:

```
void Algorithm(int array[], int nerd) {
    if(nerd < 2) return;
    bool done = true;
    for(int i = 1;; ++i) {
        if(i == nerd) {
            if(done || --nerd == 1) break;
            i = 1;
            done = true;
        }
        if (array[i] < array[i - 1]) {
            std::swap(array[i], array[i - 1]);
            done = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vxo4bfdo7)